# How to see if a specific process is running or not for 1 hour in shell

Tags: scripts, process

My process name is `test`. If I use

```
ps -ef | grep test
```

I see that process is running. Now I want to check this every 10 mins for one hour and print success if it's running successfully for one hour. 
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep test` will *always*  show positive, since the command itself includes the string `test` :). to be able to choose the best option, you need to mention what kind of process it is . A script? a regular application? A local one? Run by root?

Comment: to be specific, it's a unit test script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop; here i am using `pgrep` to check if the process is running:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
while :; do
    [ "$counter" -eq 6 ] && break
    if pgrep <process_name> &>/dev/null; then
        echo "Success !!"
        (( counter += 1 ))
        sleep 10m
    else
        echo "Process not running..exiting !!"
        break
    fi
done
```

Replace `<process_name>` with the actual name of the process you want to track.

Comment: @heemaly, thanks a lot! used grep along with ps since pgrep doesn't work for me#!/bin/bash
counter=0
while :; do
    [ "$counter" -eq 6 ] && break
    if ps -ef|grep unit_test01 &>/dev/null; then
        echo "Success !!"
        (( counter += 1 ))
        sleep 10
    else
        echo "Process not running..exiting !!"
        break
    fi
done

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop in a script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
start=$SECONDS
while (( SECONDS - start < 3600 ))
do
    sleep 10m
    pgrep -f test &>- || exit
done
echo success
```

`SECONDS` is a special variable in bash that contains the number of seconds since the script has started. `pgrep test` checks for a process named `test`. If it doesn't find one, we exit the script. If not, we `sleep` for 10 minutes.

If we didn't exit, then `pgrep` was successful. So, `echo success`.